# Is that possible to tile texture SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, textures, skshapenode

I am working with Sprite Kit and made a `SKShapeNode` using bezier path.
Drawing the path is working good.
Then I want to texture the shape node using `fillTexture`.

```
SKTexture *tex = [SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20) inTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"photo.png"]];
myNode.fillTexture = [SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20) inTexture:tex];
```

But I had no luck to show the texture on my node just like I had no texture on my node. After few weeks I found a trick that we have to set the `fillColor` to `whiteColor` to change the alpha from zero to see the texture and YES that is working, but not as I expected! So this way we see the texture but the `photo.png` width and height is stretched to width of `myNode`.

We have a big `photo.png` instead of tiled texture!

Is this a good way to tile texture a node? So if yes, what am I missing?

I am using xcode 6.4

Comment: Is what you're seeing different from the description of `fillTexture` in the `SKShapeNode` documentation?

Comment: The documentaion said that "you can use solid color or custom texture" and no more information. So I can see the texture of my custom image fill the SKShapeNode but only one image stretched to fill it and I don't have the tiled texture.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead of changing to white colour/alpha=0, you can use SKColor.clearColor().

As for the main point: your node gets filled with the image you specified, so this is the wanted/desired behaviour.

[The code that follows is for OSX; iOS might work slightly differently; particularly the focus locking part, but the principles are the same]

While NSColor has an init(patternImage) property, which can be used to fill an NSView, this does not work with a SKView. However, it can be used to compose an image offscreen, which you can then set as the texture for your node.

To compose an image, you create a new image with the size of your node, lock focus on it, and fill it with your tiled texture. You then unlock focus and use your new image as your texture.

```
let nodeFill: NSImage = createTiledBackground(myImage, size: NSSize(width: 400, height: 600))

func createTiledBackground(tileImage: NSImage, size: NSSize)->NSImage{
    let tileFill: NSImage = NSImage(size: size)
    tileFill.lockFocus()
    let currentContext = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()
    currentContext?.imageInterpolation = .High
    tileDrawing(tileImage, size: size)
    tileFill.unlockFocus()
    return tileFill
}

func tileDrawing(tileImage: NSImage, size: NSSize){
    let tileColor = NSColor(patternImage: tileImage)
    tileColor.set()
    let rect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    NSBezierPath.fillRect(rect)
}
```

Comment: Can you translate the code to objective-c please so I can understand what is going on better? because I am not using swift.

Comment: I'll try, but it will take a couple of days - I haven't written ObjectiveC since Swift was introduced, and I've never written ObjectiveC for iOS.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to it; in the meantime, have a look at http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2234246 - Erika Sadun's method is somewhat different from mine - but she's got all the right code for iOS/Objective C, so you should be able to work it out from there.

Comment: Ok I will check it but still waiting for your code translation :)